# Closing an off topic question, appropriate alternative sites not present on radio buttons

Tags: feature-request

Electronics seems to get used as a general point of first query, getting used for questions that should be on physics, the original software stackOverflow, or increasingly these days, Arduino.

However, the only two radio buttons on the 'close as off topic, another site' page are metaElectronics and superUser.

What would be involved in either adding more options to that page (at least the three mentioned above), or having a selection box so that the close proposer can suggest a site? There seems little point in having a page dedicated to suggesting specific sites, if we then have to resort to free text on the 'other (add a comment)' page.

/edit/ Most comments that I've seen say there are not enough migrations to justify it. I'm not sure whether the 'it' is keeping the migrations page tool maintained, or the migrations page itself. It's something of a self fulfilling prophesy that if the migrations tool isn't current, it won't get used to prompt migrations (duh!) My point is there is little point in having the page, and not having it point to relevant sites. I'm quite happy to see it go, and just use the 'other' page. /edit/

Comment: This was raised before, at least in chat, by me. I am a huge proponent of at least a "Close: Needs Elsewhere" Generic, as I have seen voted close at least at a 3:1 ratio for (any of your list):(superuser + meta).

Comment: This has been discussed to death many times before.  Let's not do it again.

Comment: Arduino is a no go because it's in beta. Other sites are still on the table, but in the past there haven't been a lot of migrations to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, it's a mod workload issue. The current flow is that you flag a question to be migrated (other), and a moderator reviews the flag and determines whether the post should be migrated. If there is a significant number of off-topic questions, then we (moderators) can ask the community team for additional migration target sites to be added to the list.

That being said, in the last 90 days there have been about 62 migrations requiring a moderator (excluding Arduino and SuperUser). Adding DIY to the migration list might save us 20-30 flags, or a flag every 3 days. That reduces our flag load by maybe 1%?

---

When *I* get flags for migration, the flag mentality is frequently:

> "This question should be closed, and it sorta looks like the topics
>   found on **[target migration site]**, let's migrate it."

The problem is that really bad questions get this treatment - resulting in rejected migrations (look at the SuperUser stats). Instead, when thinking about migrations, this is the criteria that should be used:

> "This is a really good question, but not exactly something we handle
>   here. It would be received well on **[target migration site]**."

---

Here's the latest 90-day migration statistics from EE.SE to various sites. I cut off the list at 1 migration a month.

[image: 90 day migration stats 12-26-16]

Comment: The RPI migrations suffer the same fault as the Arduino migrations. Auto less so.